# C# Math Issue With Division

Tags: c#, math

Why does this not work?

```
DiscountedPrice = 10
double DiscountedPrice = ((double)percentDiscounted / 100);
```

This results in 0 not 0.1 as I expected.

Comment: Did you mean to set `percentDiscounted` at the top, rather than `DiscountedPrice`?

Comment: Please show a short  but complete program demonstrating the problem. And please don't use `double` for currency values: use `decimal` instead. (It would be odd for the *price* to be the `percentDiscounted` / 100, by the way. It's the *proportion* of the discount, not the price.)

Comment: Works for me. Fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/CUoaWL

Comment: tabstop : i did percentDiscounted comes from a DB table

Answer (score 6):

This should run properly if you tried this.

```
int percentDiscounted = 10;
double discountedPrice = percentDiscounted / 100.0;
Console.WriteLine(discountedPrice);
```

You can implicitly convert an `int` to a `double` so no need to cast it.

Also, you can either use `double` or `int` type for `percentDiscounted`.

**Output**

> 0.1

Comment: @Harbz96 No problem. Oh and don't forget to press the check mark button on this answer. :)